# Unable to use metaflac from within the sandbox on MacOS

Tags: macos, sandbox, dylib, appstore-sandbox, dyld

I am trying to use metaflac from a sandboxed app, and I am putting it into the Application Scripts directory to allow execution, but its failing to load the dynamic Flac library outside the sandbox:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/Cellar/flac/1.3.2/lib/libFLAC.8.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/me/Library/Application Scripts/com.map-pin.app/metaflac
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    file system sandbox blocked open() of '/usr/local/Cellar/flac/1.3.2/lib/libFLAC.8.dylib'
    file system sandbox blocked open() of '/usr/local/lib/libFLAC.8.dylib'
    file system sandbox blocked open() of '/usr/local/Cellar/flac/1.3.2/lib/libFLAC.8.dylib'
```

This version of metaflac from home-brew install.

How can I fix this or get a metaflac binary with the library linked?